# Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project

Tags: angular, windows, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

when running **ionic cordova run browser --verbose** in the root of my Ionic4 project I get the error "Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.". See the error output bellow.

I noticed the command creates a "www" folder only to remove it again a few seconds later. When I manually add the folder after it was removed (but while the command is still running) I can prevent the error. However the "www" folder will stay empty and the served webpage will say no file found.

```
Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.
CordovaError: Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.
at Object.cdProjectRoot (C:\nvm\v11.3.0\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\util.js:170:15)
at C:\nvm\v11.3.0\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\run.js:29:40
at _fulfilled (C:\nvm\v11.3.0\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:854:54)
at C:\nvm\v11.3.0\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:883:30
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\nvm\v11.3.0\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:816:13)
at C:\nvm\v11.3.0\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:877:14
at runSingle (C:\nvm\v11.3.0\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
at flush (C:\nvm\v11.3.0\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
at internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:70:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:47:5)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

    cordova run browser --verbose exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process onBeforeExit handler: process.exit received +0ms
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process onBeforeExit handler: running 2 functions +1ms
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process error while killing process tree for 15736: { Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 15736 /T /F
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process ERROR: The process "15736" not found.
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:978:16)
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:265:5)
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process   killed: false,
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process   code: 128,
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process   signal: null,
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 15736 /T /F' } +288ms
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process onBeforeExit handler: error from function: { Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 15736 /T /F
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process ERROR: The process "15736" not found.
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:978:16)
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:265:5)
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process   killed: false,
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process   code: 128,
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process   signal: null,
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 15736 /T /F' } +6ms
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process error while killing process tree for 10672: { Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 10672 /T /F
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process ERROR: The process "10672" not found.
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:978:16)
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process     at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:395:11)
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process     at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process     at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:616:12)
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process   killed: false,
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process   code: 128,
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process   signal: null,
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 10672 /T /F' } +7ms
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process onBeforeExit handler: error from function: { Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 10672 /T /F
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process ERROR: The process "10672" not found.
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:978:16)
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process     at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:395:11)
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process     at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process     at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:616:12)
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process   killed: false,
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process   code: 128,
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process   signal: null,
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 10672 /T /F' } +6ms
ionic:cli-framework:utils:process onBeforeExit handler: exiting (exit code 1) +8ms
```

Details

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.5.0 (C:\nvm\v11.3.0\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-beta.15 (C:\Users\Simon Driesen\Projects\questionnaire-app\node_modules\@ionic\angular)
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.7.5 (C:\Users\Simon Driesen\Projects\questionnaire-app\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular)
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.1.0
   @angular/cli                  : 7.1.0
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.2.0 (C:\Users\Simon Driesen\Projects\questionnaire-app\node_modules\@ionic\angular-toolkit)

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : not installed
   Cordova Platforms     : not available
   Cordova Plugins       : not available

System:

   NodeJS : v11.3.0 (C:\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : Windows 10
```

Comment: Did you follow the instructions from the Cordova website on setting up a Cordova-based project? i.e. "Cordova create projectName" https://cordova.apache.org

Comment: check your path in the command line.make sure you are in the project folder

Comment: Thanks for the responses! 

I haven't setup a Cordova project from scratch myself yet. I can run the app fine with "ionic serve" but need to be able to run it with "ionic cordova" to be able to implement ionic-googlemaps in the project. Anyway, I will setup a project from scratch as you suggested to see if I get the same errors.

Comment: I did make sure I'm in the correct folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to create the `www` folder before running the command?

If that works, then try to add the `www` folder to your source control system (git, svn, etc...) so when you checkout the code you get that folder created, thus preventing the build system to try to recreate.

In your `.gitignore` file (if using git), add these lines:

```
 # excludes everything inside the folder
www/*
# but do not exclude .gitkeep file, so the folder can be checked into the repository
!www/.gitkeep
```

Comment: this is the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a `npm install`. Maybe some Cordova node modules are missing from your project.